# PHP, how to echo specific object data from array?

Tags: php, arrays, echo

I use this in wordpress:

```
$arr=get_post_meta($post->ID, false);
```

I receive this array:

```
Array (
[_edit_last] => Array ( [0] => 2)
[year_completed] => Array ( [0] => 2010 )
[designers] => Array ( [0] => )
[developers] => Array ( [0] => )
[producers] => Array ( [0] => )
[_edit_lock] => Array ( [0] => 1298159324 )
[name_en] => Array ( [0] => game 1)
[name_et] => Array ( [0] => game 2 )
[friends_meta] => Array ( [0] => )
)
```

How do I echo (no for, foreach, etc please) name_en data? Even `print_r ($arr->name_en);` doesn't work... I suppose it has to be something like - `echo $arr->name_en[0];` ???

Answer (score 6):

It is an array or arrays, so:

```
print_r($arr['name_en']);
```

or if you only want to get the data:

```
echo $arr['name_en'][0];
```

The `->` operator is for accessing properties of *objects*.

Comment: Yep, so it's echo $arr['name_en'][0]; Thanks ;)

Answer (score 1):

`echo $arr['name_en'][0]` should work.

Answer (score 1):

this should work

```
echo $arr[0]['year_completed'];

echo $arr[0]['designers'];
```

etc

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, as this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!