# print PHP value in an array

Tags: php, arrayobject

Hello I am trying to print a specific value from an array of objects. I am trying to get a value from an array name $allPhotos with a object's property of "nme"'s value.

This is what im trying:
echo $allPhotos[0]["nme"];

this is what the array looks like:

## var_dump($allPhotos);

```
array(2) {
  [0]=> object(Photo)#1 (10) { 
    ["product"]=> array(5) { 
      ["PKG1"]=> string(4) "6500" 
      ["PKG2"]=> string(4) "9500" 
      ["8x10"]=> string(4) "1500" 
      ["5x7"]=> string(3) "750" 
      ["4x6"]=> string(3) "300" 
    } 
    ["price"]=> NULL ["sku"]=> string(1) "1" 
    ["nme"]=> string(5) "test1" 
    ["dir"]=> string(51) "http://" 
    ["status"]=> string(1) "1" ["gallery"]=> string(16) "Church Directory"    
    ["galleryCover"]=> string(1) "0" 
    ["family"]=> string(0) "" 
    ["familyCover"]=> string(0) "" 
} 

[1]=> object(Photo)#2 (10) { 
  ["product"]=> array(5) { 
    ["PKG1"]=> string(4) "6500" 
    ["PKG2"]=> string(4) "9500" 
    ["8x10"]=> string(4) "1500" 
    ["5x7"]=> string(3) "750" 
    ["4x6"]=> string(3) "300" 
  } 
  ["price"]=> NULL 
  ["sku"]=> string(1) "2" 
  ["nme"]=> string(5) "test2" 
  ["dir"]=> string(51) "http://" 
  ["status"]=> string(1) "1" 
  ["gallery"]=> string(16) "Church Directory" 
  ["galleryCover"]=> string(1) "0" 
  ["family"]=> string(0) "" 
  ["familyCover"]=> string(0) "" 
 } 
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried `echo $allPhotos[0]["nme"];` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe `echo $allPhotos[0]->nme;` should work.

Comment: I believe so too. Have no experience with this sort of array indexing as I haven't needed it yet, though a simple Google search got me the same answer. Might also be a duplicate of this: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5054520/php-how-to-echo-specific-object-data-from-array)

Comment: Yep that's it, Thanks a lot. Just wondering why does $allPhotos[0]["nme"]; not work? is it because it is still in an object in the array?

Comment: The array is an array of objects.  The object `$allPhotos[0]` is not an array, and so you have to use `->` to access its properties.  Think of it this way:  `$n = $allPhotos[0];  echo $n->nme;`