# Codeigniter pass array to view, or convert array to object with foreach loop

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, object, foreach

recently I came across a problem where I would need to generate an object from CodeIgniter PHP foreach loop. Basically I need to filter through my email list and generate the object based on the result, then pass it to the view and use another foreach loop to list the content out there.

Here's what I have and it successfully generates an array $email_raw, but I couldn't find the right way to generate it as an object instead:

PHP:

```
    $email_preliminary=$this->db->select('email')->get('user'); 

    $email_raw = array();

    foreach ($email_preliminary->result() as $row):

        $email_to_test=$row->email;

        if(filter_var($email_to_test, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)||preg_match('/\d*[1-9]\d*/', $email_to_test))
        {
            $email_raw[] = $email_to_test;
        }

        else{

        }
    endforeach;
```

People suggested that I use:

```
                $email_raw[] = (object)array('email'=>$email_to_test);
```

But the error msg says its not an object.

What are other ways I can generate $email_raw as an object so I can pass it to the view and use foreach to list the content out there?

Many thanks!

Update:

per request, here's rest of the controller:

```
        $data['record']=array_unique($email_raw);

        $this->load->view('login&signup/signup_test_get_wrong_email_view', $data);
```

and the view I use:

```
      <?php foreach ($record->result() as $row): ?> 

    <span><?php echo $row->email; ?></span><br>

      <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: At the end of generating the `$email_raw`, use `$email_raw = (object)$email_raw;`. The whole `$email_raw` variable becomes object.

Comment: Why do you want to generate an object instead of an array? An array will work just fine and it is generally more versatile.

Comment: I think you've mistaken this for an associative array otherwise there is no need to cast your array to an object since there is no difference between the usage of these two in your case.

Comment: @machineaddict I tried but the output from the view says: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string. Is there a way I can generate $email_raw directly as object in the foreach loop?

Comment: @Dan and MahanGM, CodeIgniter view says I have to use an object otherwise it says: Call to a member function result() on a non-object in

Comment: Please post the rest of the controller code and the view part where you iterate with foreach loop

Comment: Look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5054520/php-how-to-echo-specific-object-data-from-array or other questions like it...

Comment: @machineaddict I updated the question with the rest of the controller and view

Comment: @Dan I don't think it's an array in array; I'm just looking for a way to store the variable as an object that can be displayed again using foreach loop in the view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[foreach](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) can iterate object and arrays. You don't have to convert your array to object.

Leave the controller like it is above:

```
$email_preliminary=$this->db->select('email')->get('user'); 

$email_raw = array();

foreach ($email_preliminary->result() as $row):

    $email_to_test=$row->email;

    if(filter_var($email_to_test, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)||preg_match('/\d*[1-9]\d*/', $email_to_test))
    {
        $email_raw[] = $email_to_test;
    }

    else{

    }
endforeach;

// ... code

$data['record']=array_unique($email_raw);

$this->load->view('login&signup/signup_test_get_wrong_email_view', $data);
```

In the view you simply iterate that array you've just constructed:

```
<?php foreach ($record as $email): ?> 

    <span><?php echo $email; ?></span><br>

<?php endforeach; ?>
```

I guess your doubt comes from lack of knowing how the `$data['record']` variable looks like. Use `print_r($data['record']);` right after `$data['record']` is being set.

Comment: tnx a lot. it really helped me.