# How to echo form data from array

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, forms

For a wordpress form I look for the entries using:

```
<?php
print_r($entry); exit;
?>
```

This gives me:

```
Array ( [1.1] => 2015 [1.2] => Infiniti [1.3] => Q70 )
```

How do I write the full php to echo these chosen entries individually that are entered on the form (from a 3 stage chained select field).

I have read this [PHP, how to echo specific object data from array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5054520/php-how-to-echo-specific-object-data-from-array) and for his scenario he needs:

```
echo $arr['name_en'][0];
```

But I have no apparent 'name_en' equivalents

I am new to php so if I need to define my version of $arr help with that for this scenario would be great $arr = $entry['field'] or something?

Comment: have you tried `echo $arr[1.1];`? This should print 2015

Comment: I was making a Gravitypdf custom template in php which didn't support Gravity Form's 'chained select' add-on until today. I can now pull the data array out like this  https://gravitypdf.com/documentation/v4/developer-php-form-data-array/ . It shows as [field] => array ( [1] => array ( [0] => 2015 [1] => Infiniti [2] => Q70)). So I can echo 'year' as $year = $form_data['field']['1']['0']; where 1 is the field reference on the form and 0 is first entry on chained select. Then 'Year is <?php echo $year; ?> now prints into the pdf. Thanks for the answers, just took me a while to work it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is your array

```
Array ( 
   [1.1] => 2015,
   [1.2] => Infiniti,
   [1.3] => Q70 
)
```

To print single values in PHP you have to use a syntax like this:

```
echo $array_name[1.1];
echo $array_name[1.2];
echo $array_name[1.3];
```

And the output will be

```
2015
Infiniti
Q70
```

Have a look to the official documentation to understand how an array works [PHP Manual: Arrays](http://php.net/manual/it/language.types.array.php)

Comment: Thanks I think it was just a peculiarity of the setup I was using as to why it wasn't working, see my comment above.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure it response to your question.
Here is how to echo all value inside an array.

```
$arr = array('1.1' => 2015, '1.2' => 'Infiniti', '1.3' => 'Q70');
foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
  echo $value;
}
```